# ListView se modifica al superponerse el teclado en Android

Tags: android-studio, firebase, android-layout, listview, android-listview

Tengo una actividad con dos EditText en la parte superior y un ListView debajo de esos dos campos.
Al entrar en la actividad el ListView se llena con los datos que se reciben de una BD Firebase.
Al seleccionar uno de los elementos del ListView los datos se pasan a los campos para poderlos modificar o borrar, y si marco alguno de los dos TextEdit se despliega el teclado quedando los últimos elementos ocultos debajo de él.

Hasta aquí todo funciona correctamente.

Pero al modificar cualquier elemento del ListView, después de que se actualice en la BD y se vuelva a generar el ListView, UNO de los elementos que antes quedaban debajo del teclado se duplica con el primer elemento de la lista.
Es decir, si el teclado tenía oculto a partir del quinto elemento en la lista al ocultarse el teclado ESE elemento es el mismo que el primero de la lista.
Al consultar la BD está todo correcto, no existen registros duplicados y las modificaciones se realizan bien.

Este es el código del evento que se lanza cada vez que se actualiza la BD.

```
    BDreferencia.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        lista.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot instantanea : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
          Empresa empresa = new Empresa(String.valueOf(instantanea.getKey()),
                                        String.valueOf(instantanea.child("nombre").getValue()));
          lista.add(empresa);
        }

        miListView.setAdapter(miAdaptador);
        miAdaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
        miListView.requestFocus();
      }
```

Ese es el código que construye cada vista de cada elemento del ListView.

```
  public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;

    if (view == null){
      view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.tarjeta_empresa,null);
      Empresa mEmpresa = mList.get(position);
      TextView codigo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lytTarjetacmpCodigo);
      TextView nombre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lytTarjetacmpNombre);
      codigo.setText(mEmpresa.getCodigo());
      nombre.setText(mEmpresa.getNombre());
    }
    return view;
  }
```

Este es el Layout de la actividad.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Empresas">

    <!--<include layout="@layout/content_empresas" />-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/lytCmpCodigo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="código centro"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColorHint="#DCEDC8"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/lytCmpNombre"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="nombre centro"
            android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
            android:textColorHint="#FFDCEDC8"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="selecciona para modificar/borrar"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lv1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Y este es el Layout de la vista de cada elemento del ListView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/lytTarjetaEmpresa">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lytTarjetacmpCodigo"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="aa"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lytTarjetacmpNombre"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="bb"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: pone un break point cuando volves de Firebase con la lista y chequea que lista tenga los valores que queres mostrar en tu pantalla, si estos valores tienen el elemento duplicado, el problema esta en la query y no en el teclado, si los elementos no estan duplicados es un problema del adaptador

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo he solucionado.
El problema estaba en como se construye el layout.
El ListView estaba dentro de un linearlayout que a su vez estaba dentro de otro linearlayout.
He sacado el LinearLayout que contine el ListView, y lo he colocado a continuación del primer LinearLayout y ya funciona correctamente.
Muchas gracias a todos por la ayuda.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    tools:context=".ActividadTienda">

    <!--<include layout="@layout/content_empresas" />-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/lytCmpCodigo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="código tienda"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColorHint="#DCEDC8"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtErrorCodigo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#FF0700"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/lytCmpNombre"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="nombre tienda"
                android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
                android:textColorHint="#FFDCEDC8"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtErrorNombre"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#FF0700"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="selecciona para modificar/borrar"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```